# Conflicting components Joomla

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, joomla, conflict

Can't clear the problem with conflicting modules and menu. I have tried to disable jQuery and JS, use non conflict but there is a problem with mobile menu (you should minimize browser window to see mobile menu) on the website. Sometimes it appears on homepage when mobile menu goes behind the slider and is not visible. However if you go to NEWS page you will see calendar icon also conflicting with mobile menu. Do anyone have any solution?

Thank you!

[image: Homepage]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to order the elements with z-index in the right order.

Add this code to your css file templates/shaper_helix_ii/css/template.css

```
.sp-mobile-menu{z-index: 9999;}
.sp-main-menu-toggler{z-index: 99999;}
```